# How to run test for randomness on a ternary cyclic sequence?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-variable, runs

I would like to do a run test for randomness on a ternary sequence ($x_n \in \{0,1,2\}$) where a run is said to continue if the value increases by 1 cyclically (i.e. $(x_{n+1}-x_n)=1 \text{ mod } 3$). I know the sequence is limited to exactly 1000 elements only (if you are interested, it's for https://www.kaggle.com/c/rock-paper-scissors/). Hence, the probability that a run continues is exactly 1/3 for a random sequence.

So I can calculate the frequencies $n_1, n_2, n_3, \ldots$ for run lengths $1,2,3,\ldots$.

How can I make a aggregate test metric from that and what distribution do I use to test for randomness?

Comment: Well, you can calculate the expected number $n_k$ of runs of length $k$ (e.g., using Markov Chains, or just by simulation), then compare the observed number to the expected number using, e.g., an $\chi^2$ test. But then you could still have a nonrandom assignment: I could use runs whose distribution follows the expectation, but I first put in the longest run, then the second-longest etc., so the *order* of the runs is nonrandom.

Comment: I saw classical test just count the total number of runs. Is that better in this case, given my sequence is only 1000 long?